# Report missing data in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, missing-data

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fbb0)**

---

I have a dynamic long (>1000) list of components and their respective asset types in Excel. Example:

```
Component                   Asset Type
0738.D100.L00.55            9211.D108.D07.01_02.02
0738.D100.L00.71            0738.D100.L00.55_04.04
0738.D100.M02.55            0738.D100.M00.60_03.03
0990.OH05.A00.09            0738.D100.M00.60_03.03
```

Some of these combinations may not exist in the SQL database. I want a query that outputs these combinations.

Components and their respective asset type can be requested as follows

```
Select C.Code, AT.Code From astComponents C 
Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId
```

I created a method which uses a temp table to compare with, but tested with 1250 combinations, this method runs slow at ~6.5 seconds, of which creating the table is ~2 seconds.

```
Create Table 
#Temp(Component nvarchar(50) Collate Latin1_General_BIN, AssetType nvarchar(50) Collate Latin1_General_BIN) 
Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) Values ('0738.D100.L00.55','9211.D108.D07.01_02.02');
Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) Values ('0738.D100.L00.71','0738.D100.L00.55_04.04');
Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) Values ('0738.D100.M02.55','0738.D100.M00.60_03.03');
Insert Into #Temp (Component, AssetType) Values ('0990.OH05.A00.09','0738.D100.M00.60_03.03');
--more Inserts left out

Select Distinct 
    Compare.Component,  
    Compare.AssetType 
From astComponents C
    Join astAssetTypes AT ON AT.Id = C.AssetTypeId
    Right Join #Temp Compare ON Compare.AssetType = AT.Code And Compare.Component = C.Code
Where C.Code is null
```

In [the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fbb0), the expected outcome is below if we use the top example as our data to check. These component-asset type combinations do not exist in the fiddle database.

```
Component                   Asset Type
0738.D100.M02.55            0738.D100.M00.60_03.03
0990.OH05.A00.09            0738.D100.M00.60_03.03
```

I want a faster method. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the source of component list? Do you have to insert them row by row? By the way, you don't seem to use the CTE `Compare`.

Comment: The source is an excel sheet. Because it exceeds 1000 records, I need to insert row by row (or do 1000 each time, but this was easier to code). And you're right about the query, only noticed now. I transformed it from a genuine CTE that worked the other way around but was much slower

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you want:

```
select c.*
from #temp c join
     astAssetTypes t 
     on t.AssetType = c.AssetType
where not exists (select 1
                  from components co
                  where co.component = c.code and
                        co.AssetTypeId = t.id
                 )
```

For this query, you want indexes on:

- `astAssetTypes(AssetType, id)`
- `components(component, AssetTypeId)`

Comment: I could not get this to execute, which is probably due to your comment on indexes. What do you mean by this, exactly?

Comment: Indexes are not necessary to execute a query, they help to make it faster. There is an extra `join` in Gordon's query (`astComponents c join --<-- This one`), if you remove it you should have better luck.

Comment: @TimStack . . . The table aliases were backwards.  They should be fixed now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff working through the errors, but I can't make it execute... [It falls over the astComponents c join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ac5d7/18)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited your answer and fixed the query

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am not familiar with indexes. From what I can see they're a part of the database, rather than the query. However I have limited read-only rights. Could you expand?

Comment: @TimStack, Indexes are indeed database objects. If you can't/are not allowed to create indexes, see how the query runs without them. It's too broad to discuss here.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot create indexes. This method is [significantly slower than mine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ac5d7/33)  (23ms vs 8ms)

Comment: @TimStack . .. 8 ms is pretty fast.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, for only 4 records.... I'm testing more than a thousand against a much larger datebase table

Comment: @TimStack . . . You should base your timings on realistically sized data.  And, if you care about performance, then you (or someone else) should be able to create indexes.