# Performing find on recordset with criteria for two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am attempting to perform a `Find` on a recordset with two criteria, one for each field. I am, however, running into the following error:

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

```vb
Set rs = getdata("Select Distinct astAssetTypes.Code AT, astComponents.Code Comp FROM dbo.astComponents JOIN dbo.astAssetTypes ON astAssetTypes.Id = astComponents.AssetTypeId WHERE astAssetTypes.Code IN(" & ComponentCode & ")")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.Find rs.Fields(1).Name & "='" & tempArr(b, 1) & "' AND " & rs.Fields(0).Name & "='" & tempArr(b, 9) & "'"
End If
```

Printing the find criteria results in:
`Comp='0738.D100.L00.55' AND AT='9211.D108.D07.01_02.02'`

I'm puzzled as to why it's not working. Judging by how online sources stating such a Find function is possible, I don't see why this won't process.

The query is valid, `getdata` is a custom function:

```vb
Public Function getdata(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim connstring As String
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

connstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=omitted;Connect Timeout=180"
cnn.Open connstring

Set getdata = New ADODB.Recordset
    getdata.CursorLocation = adUseClient
getdata.Open query, connstring, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

cnn.Close
End Function
```

Comment: ADO recordsets only allow searching on one column, unlike DAO.

Comment: maybe you can do the second search on the resultset of the first search ?

Comment: @GuidoG I could, but that would increase the processing time. Unfortunately it seems an impossible task to do what I want based off of Rory's comment

Comment: Adding the where condition to  your initial SQL should be faster!?

Comment: @krishKM It would not as I am looping through a table of a couple of thousand records. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790755/report-missing-data-in-database)

Comment: try a global connection and do your 1000 searches using SQL and measure the performance. I'm pretty sure it'll still be faster than your 1000 find or filter executions.